# Some useful AWK scripts for TeX users

Tags: editors, awk

Some people like old cars, some like antiques, and I like classical Unix toolbox. Most likely the second (after shell script) scripting language that any old school Unix user learn is AWK. It is an indispensable tool of any cool teacher when it comes for dealing with grade books. It is however lesser known that AWK is a very cool tool when it comes to TeXing. I am not talking just about cool tools as bbl2html.awk (several different scripts) but also just a regular editing. I would like to ask community to share its favorite AWK scripts for TeX editing. Mine are also coming soon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The vc bundle](http://ctan.org/tex-archive/support/vc) is basically a glorified awk script. It works by getting your favourite version control system to spit out the status of the current branch, piping that into an awk script which then writes stuff to a `.tex` file which you then `\input`. This file defines the macros that you the use in the document.